How to run Testcafe 3.5 with chrome headless=new with the testrunner API?
We are using Testcafe v3.5 with Gherkin Testcafe library which works great.
I want to experiment with the new Chrome Headless that can be started with the option
chromium --headless=new.
But we use the testrunner-api and my browser-string looks like this:
chrome:headless:emulation:cdpPort=9222;
I tried several things like:
chrome:headless=new:emulation:cdpPort=9222;
chrome:headless:new:emulation:cdpPort=9222;
chromium:headless=new:emulation:cdpPort=9222;
chromium:headless:new:emulation:cdpPort=9222;

But I can not get it to work. Can it be done, if so how?
Otherwise we wait for gherkin-testcafe to be updated with Testcafe 3.6 as a dependency.

You can pass the Chrome '--headless=new' flag after the automation port. Try running your test with the browser string 'chrome:emulation:cdpPort=9222 --headless=new'.
